# How to scale down an image so it looks correct on mobile device

Tags: css

I am having an issue scaling my image down for a mobile device. If you view this link in the desktop, the image is fine:

https://www.thecompleteapproach.co.uk/go/success-to-soar/

But view it in a device and it's zoomed in. I need to get it scaled so that it looks good on a mobile device as well as desktop. Can someone point me to the right direction?

CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url(./wp-content/uploads/2000/01/image_example.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: background-size: contain or  background-size: 100% auto

Comment: Ah, easy as that, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `background-size: contain` will scale the image based on the size of the browser window. Just as @MTK mentioned, you could also use `background-size: 100%` or `background-size: 100% auto`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(./wp-content/uploads/2000/01/image_example.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check image height and set height accordingly.

```css
body{
   background-image:url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/home/av/images/overview/retail/why_apple__genwe8js9fee_large_2x.jpg);
   width: 100%;
   background-size: contain;
   background-position: top center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 390px;
}
```